# Specific selection range in number input

Tags: javascript, html, selection

I couldn't find any solution for selecting a range of characters in a `<input type="number">` field.
Is it possible?

EDIT: I'm sorry I didn't mention it. By "range", I meant `setSelectionRange()`.

Comment: You can use `min` and `max`

Comment: An input type number should only accept number, I know it is obvious but you were talking about _range of characters_.

Comment: I think it is not characters it is numbers. For range of number you can use like `<input type="number" name="quantity" min="10" max="15">`

Comment: By "selecting range", I meant an equivalent to `setSelectionRange()`.

Answer (score 0):

You really should not be asking questions like that here.
With a simple search you could have figured it out.

I will answer it for you however and also assume you mean 'Number' instead of 'Characters'.

You also have to take into account that this is HTML5 and can have browser compatibility issues and you will need to add a polyfill for older browsers.

You can also use step = "any" to specify the value granularity of the value.

```
<input type="number" name="quantity" min="1" max="5">
```

Answer (score 0):

Further to the response from @Scor3keeper if you want to handle this yourself rather than relying on the browser's implementation of min/max you could do something like this:

```
<script>
  function handleChange(input) {
    if (input.value < 0) input.value = 0;
    if (input.value > 100) input.value = 100;
  }
</script>
```

Then declare the input box like this:

```
<input type="text" onchange="handleChange(this);" />
```

This is slightly more robust than modern browser's implementation which allows you to paste or type numbers out of range. However the browser implementation does give the user validation alerts.

Comment: By "selecting range", I meant an equivalent to `setSelectionRange()`.